# Composition of EZ-Vision® DNA Dye?

Tags: molecular-biology

I'm looking for the composition of the EZ-Vision DNA Dye for electrophoresis visualization. I could not find anything helpful on the web.

I would appreciate a lot your help :)

Comment: Presumably you're asking for safety reasons. Their safety data sheet is missing for that product on their website. You'd be justified in directly contacting the manufacturer on this topic.

Comment: Read the label of bottles. Find was there any datasheets or such provided with the bottle. Laboratories keeps various data-books and datasheets so ask for that. Ask your teachers/ guides about  its composition.  Googling is no difficult task.  If you are able to handle with DNA (for me it is enough difficult) why could you face difficulty in google search?

Comment: The MSDS does not specify which compound is actually present in the solution. A quick google search does not show what is composition of the solution, except for DMSO.

Comment: https://www.amresco-inc.com/media.acux?path=/media/products/dfu/dfu-N472.pdf  was it any helpful?

Comment: Sometimes companies keep some 'trade-secrets'; however I think main components should be mentioned. I  too feel discomfort in mind while working with something even if any 1 component  I do not know.

Comment: @Ashafix me too. I also could not found something helpful in Google within a short time.

Comment: @AlwaysConfused I found that info sheet as well, but sadly it doesn't provide the components. Thanks, anyway :)

Comment: Then you should write "I could not found anything helpful on web", than "I'm not very good in googling". That would help directly understand the research effort . (as well I'm not moderator), Moderation in stack websites is  done in tough way.

Comment: If a company keeps some trade-secret (I'm not sure if this the case), or even many well-popular facts are not available in web.

Answer (score 3):

Contacted technical support and received the following response:
"Unfortunately, the information you requested is proprietary and we will not be able to share the images of excitation-emission spectra of EZ-Vision® Bluelight DNA Dye and the chemical structure of the dye. "